# Microbenchmarking dplyr's rename

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm writing a set of convenience functions for cleaning up some data exports and am renaming some large sets (~100,000 records) for better legibility. Since this is mostly going to be used as a utility, I thought I'd give the standard evaluation (SE) version of the `dplyr` verbs a shot instead of their non-standard (NSE) counterparts. However, when I microbenchmark them, the SE versions seem to be significantly slower:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(
+   rename = rename(exports, newid = recordid),
+   rename_ = rename_(exports, .dots = setNames("recordid", "newid")),
+   times = 10000
+ )
Unit: microseconds
    expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq       max neval
  rename 132.343 146.2445 177.7755 152.3795 170.249  9947.417 10000
 rename_ 293.312 306.8130 371.8973 313.9005 358.598 10243.931 10000
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just a poor application for these functions?

Comment: `setNames()` might actually be the culprit there.  But all you're doing is setting new names so why is this even a big deal?  It's never going to take much longer than that.

Comment: Eh, it's my first time diving into the dplyr's SE functions. I'm not so much worried about optimising this particular instance to death—just looking for explanations as the docs for rename_ seem somewhat scant.

Comment: @mattpolicastro `substitute` function may be useful if you will go with SE way somewhere.